# How to call a rails namespaced api from web namespaced controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is like this:

I have a rails project. Inside of it, i have a namespace/subdomain for the api and a namespace/rootdomain for the web.
I want to put all the business logic inside the api, and simply call it from the web namespaced controller.

http://api.example.com => api
http://example.com     => web

Any ideas on how i have to organize the project? how do i make the internal calls? or is another (better) way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

use this :

Sooner or later each Rails developer come to a point when he wants to build his first API.

Among the first things you have to take care of are your controllers.

If you want your API to be fast (and I bet you do) then you should consider using `ActionController::Metal`.

The trick is that `ActionController::Base` has many Middlewares that are not necessary for the API, by using Metal controller with minimum modules included, the one can achieve up to 40% speedup.
Lets see what your basic metal controller may looks like:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  include ActionController::Rendering        # enables rendering
  include ActionController::MimeResponds     # enables serving different content types like :xml or :json
  include AbstractController::Callbacks      # callbacks for your authentication logic

  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views" # you have to specify your views location as well
end
```

Comment: it didn't answer my question, but it helps me anyway with the speed part. Say that you have a controller that renders an html view. I want to retrieve (for example) all the post but from the api subdomain. How do i do that ?